# Best way to work with a large csv file for fast filtering, sorting and extraction (in memory?)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, elasticsearch, in-memory-database

I have a legacy static csv with about 1 million records and a 1gb size. There are about 300 fields per row.

Some of the fields are denormalized one-to-many relations like for each order `Category_1, Category_2, Category_3,...,Category_20` etc However the number of category fields can be max 20 and are empty in case there are fewer than 20 categories or if there were more than 20 categories, the extra categories were omitted. Field values can be like `"DX001 - Dairy"`, `"CX002 - Cosmetics"` Now the order of categories isn't fixed. so `DX001` can be in any of the N categories (`Category_1, Category_2, Category_3, Category_N`) fields.

There is another field for `Amount` which is in dollars. like `$1,256.25`

Now I need to do things like search for all orders that have categories with "DX001" or "CX002" with a Amount > $1000 and sort it by amount and then export data with just these records to a csv, to be served to the user through a web interface.

What tech stack would be most suitable for a solution with fast processing (a few seconds to process the queries and make the csv available) with reasonable cost? Personally I have worked on a huge scale and used elasticsearch as my data source for a project with terabytes of data. But I personally think that will be too costly as well as be overkill for this use case. Or will i need to import this into a traditional database? Can something be done in-memory using python for this? As I am familiar with Python, but can adopt any other language as well if there is a solution available. Would appreciate some help.

PS: I looked at pandas, but I wasn't able to figure out how I will query the categories by searching each of N fields for a list of categories. So if you know how to solve that problem in pandas please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a database?  The legacy .csv file is static, so why even continue to deal with it? I think you might get the best performance if you were to do a one-time conversion to a more suitable format, and then query that new source.  I'm most familiar with MS SQL Server, but mySQL or any of the other open-source SQL productions should be able to make short work of a task like this.  You could even go so far as to renormalize those fields and put them back into one-many subtables to improve performance further.

Comment: I could certainly do that, however the output of this csv is used in other systems so I'll still need it for now. Like i need to filter, sort and export the csv in the same format. So if something else can be done, would prefer that.

Comment: If this is a question of whether or not pandas will work for what you need, the answer if yes, it will work. As far as what the second question is, are you just trying to get the unique values in multiple columns?

Comment: I think I understand.  Personally, I would use some sort of piped input/output which would read records, parse them, and export...unless you need the results of the entire file to make certain determinations of how to do the sorting/filtering.  I've done similar data file filtering in PowerShell using pipeline.  Python shouldn't be that much different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best and easiest solution for your problem is [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) (in-process SQL OLAP database management system)

It has a powerful CSV parser which can detects lots of dialets, file formats, column types and [more](https://duckdb.org/2023/10/27/csv-sniffer.html)
And then you can process the database/table in SQL, even several millions of lines / gigabytes on a regular desktop computer.
You can use it with a Python API or import Pandas dataframe